# creating llvm load from a c++ bool

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a bool in my c++ program.

```
bool foo;
```

I would like to create a llvm value that reads `foo`. (to be used by other llvm code) Can I just refer to foo by name? Or by address since its location will not change?

```
llvm::value* loadFoo = ??
```

Comment: Let's clarify: you want to use `foo` from LLVM code executed by `llvm::ExecutionEngine` in the same process?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a global external variable in your LLVM code:

```
@foo = external global i8
```

Or, with API:

```
llvm::GlobalVariable* fooVar = new GlobalVariable(
 /*Module=*/      Module, 
 /*Type=*/        llvm::Type::getInt8Ty(Context),
 /*isConstant=*/  false,
 /*Linkage=*/     GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage,
 /*Initializer=*/ nullptr, 
 /*Name=*/        "foo"  // (1)
);
```

Then you can treat `fooVar` as a pointer to `foo` value:

```
llvm::Value* loadFoo = builder.CreateLoad(fooVar);
```

One last thing, to actually tell `ExecutionEngine` that `fooVar` is `bool foo`, you need to do that explicitly:

```
executionEngine.addGlobalMapping(fooVar, &foo);
```

Or, by name (1):

```
executionEngine.addGlobalMapping("foo", &foo);
```